# formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. En Angular 13. Angular Material autocomplete

Tags: angular, formularios, angular-material

Tengo un formulario muy sencillo con un Autocomplete de Angular Material que hace su trabajo, pero recibo el error "Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive." Decir que aun estoy muy verde con Angular.

TS:

```
export class SquareFootDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  plantFormControl = new FormControl();
  options: PlantInterface[] = this.data.plants;
  filteredPlants!: Observable<PlantInterface[]>;

  constructor(
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SquareFootDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {sf: SquarefootInterface, plant: PlantInterface, plants: PlantInterface[]}
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.filteredPlants = this.plantFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => (typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name)),
      map(name => (name ? this.filterPlants(name) : this.options.slice())),
    );
  }

  // Show plant name in new plant form when filtering
  displayFn(plant: PlantInterface): string {
    return plant && plant.name ? plant.name : '';
  }

  // Filter results when type a name
  private filterPlants(value: string): PlantInterface[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.options.filter(option => option.name.includes(filterValue));
  }

  save(){
    this.dialogRef.close(this.plantFormControl.value);
  }

  close(){
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

HTML:

```
<form *ngIf="!data.sf.plant" (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <mat-form-field  appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Añadir cultivo</mat-label>
            <input type="text"
                formControlName="plantName"
                placeholder="Selecciona un cultivo"
                matInput
                [formControl]="plantFormControl"
                [matAutocomplete]="auto">
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let plant of filteredPlants | async" [value]="plant.name">
                <img [src]="'assets/plants/thumbs/' + plant.img" width="30" class="mat-autocomplete--img"> 
                {{plant.name}}        
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div class="row between-xs">
        <button mat-raised-button type="submit">
          Crear
        </button>
        <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="close()">
          Cancelar
        </button>
      </div>
  </form>
```

He tratado de establecer un FormGroup con los form controls, pero cuando lo hago, deja de funcionar el autocomplete:

INTENTO ARREGLARLO CON:

```
form!: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(): void {
    // New Bed Form onInit
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      plantName: ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

Pero al hacerlo, deja de funcionar el autocomplete.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que asignar el `FormGroup` al `form`:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
```